# How do I print an item outside of a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, particle-system

Beginner here,

If I create a loop to create some lists, how would you print a specific list outside of the loop?

This is my code so far:

```
import random

for i in range(0,5):
  "particle = [mass/posx/posy/velx/vely]"
  posx=random.randint(1,10)
  posy=random.randint(1,10)
  velx=random.randint(-0,0)
  vely=random.randint(-0,0)
  particle=[mass,posx,posy,velx,vely]
  print(particle)
```

How could I then, for example, print the 3rd list outside of the for i in range ... ?

So its on the lines of

```
print particle3
```

Comment: Why cannot I see the third list here?

Comment: At each iteration, the previously created list is overwritten by the new list. You should create a list of lists.

Comment: Do you want to print particle or particle1?

Comment: @PSM Can you figure out what `particle1` is?

Comment: I can print all the lists within the loop however I want to specifically take the 3rd list after the loop. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I made and edit so it is particle3. So I would like to print the 3rd loop list

Comment: It's not clear what you're looping through.  There's no reference to _i_ inside your for loop.

Comment: This is for a particle system :) I am creating here 5 particles which will interact. I would then like to specifically selection one particular particle to manipulate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should initalize list outside of loop as you are overiding the list on each iteration

```
import random
particle=[]
for i in range(5): # you do not need 0 in range
  #"particle = [mass/posx/posy/velx/vely]"
    posx=random.randint(1,10)
    posy=random.randint(1,10)
    velx=random.randint(-0,0)
    vely=random.randint(-0,0)
    particle.append([mass,posx,posy,velx,vely]) # no idea what mass is
print(particle[2]) # should print third list
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave it a go but it only prints the 3rd item in the last list created by the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: you have to initialize a list as well. the solution will be creating a list of lists. try executing the code separately to your code while chipping in correct values

Comment: P erry. This only prints the third item, because you asked to print only the third item, to print other items just change it to `print(particle([item]))`

Comment: I hadn't added in the append, it works now. Thank you very much @mad_

Answer (score 1):

So, you basically want to print `particle` on the 3rd iteration of the `for` loop, right?

Since i increments on each run:

import random

```
for i in range(0,5):
  "particle = [mass/posx/posy/velx/vely]"
  posx=random.randint(1,10)
  posy=random.randint(1,10)
  velx=random.randint(-0,0)
  vely=random.randint(-0,0)
  particle=[mass,posx,posy,velx,vely]
  # We use 2 because it's the 3rd loop when i starts at 0
  if i == 2:
    print(particle)
```

Comment: OP said "for example" so a list of lists is maybe a better solution

Comment: I agree and after reading mad_'s answer, his is probably better. I'd delete mine, but at this point, I'm not sure this *isn't* what OP is looking for.